# Extract word between two words in Tableau

Tags: tableau-api, calculation

My data in a single column looks like this

```
Environment: PROD_A
JobName: MY JOB NAME 1
MemName: Some_Script_names
```

My aim is to create a calculated field where it fetches JobName.
In above sample. The output should be **MY_JOB_NAME_1**

Here's my code in Tableau -

```
MID([Description],FIND([Description],"JobName: ")+9,
FIND([Description],"MemName: ")-FIND([Description],"JobName: ")-9)
```

The above logic is same as excel function below. It basically finds first word and last word and then picks the one in between.

```
=MID(A1,SEARCH("JobName: ",A1)+9,SEARCH("MemName",A1)-SEARCH("JobName: ",A1)-9)
```

Issue -
Tableau is showing blank data. Not sure where my logic is wrong. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Is each line in your sample a separate row or are they all in one row?

Comment: @Bernardo single row

Answer (score 1):

I see that you commented that the text is in one cell and not one column as you wrote in question.

This finds the JobName and uses that position plus the lenght of it as the startposition, then finds MemName as the endposition (and calculates the number of characters between them)

```
=MID(A1,FIND("JobName: ",A1)+LEN("JobName: "),FIND("MemName",A1,FIND("JobName: ",A1)+LEN("JobName: ")+1)-(FIND("JobName: ",A1)+Len("JobName: ")))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to use REGEX funtions (depending on your data source).  Try this: REGEXP_EXTRACT([Data],'JobName: (.*)')

Answer (score 0):

The following tableau calc works, this assumes that there is no space after MY_JOB_NAME_1 and "MemName:"

```
MID([Text], 
FIND([Text],'JobName: ')+10, 
FIND( 
MID([Text], 
FIND([Text],'JobName: ')+10)," ")-9)
```